# angular JS Rest web service call Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: angular, rest, angular2-services

I am trying to consume rest webservice that is deployed at my local jboss server and I am getting following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8092/authentication/GB. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I am using below code to call this web service:

```
let myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');    
        //myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Basic 11111hcmU6c2VsZmNhcmU=');   
        //myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', '*');
        myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'true');

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders });
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8092/authentication/GB', options)
        .map(res => res.json().data);
```

Can anyone please give me any pointer to solve this issue

Comment: Are you using cors middleware in your restAPI ?

Comment: Solution Depends on your web service technology, you need to enable CORS on the web service end, Cheers!!

Comment: how to do it .. I am using spring boot rest controller.